# Why is the submit button value passed when using the GET method in HTML?

Tags: html, get, request

I am using the the "GET" method in a form on my website. For some reason it is passing the value of the submit button to the url. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Form:

```
<form method="GET" action="searcht1.php">
    <input type="text" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Url:

```
searcht1.php?search=colin+pacelli&submit=Submit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's supposed to happen. If you don't want that, do not define `name` attribute on the button. You probably want `value` instead, to show the user what the button is for.

Also, this question has nothing to do with PHP; it is purely about HTML semantics.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the `name` attribute makes the submit button a [“successful control”](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) (in HTML 4.01 terminology) when it is used for form submission. This causes the name=value pair from it to be included in the form data.

Note that in your case, this data is `name=`*foo* where *foo* is the browser-dependent default value of the button. It could be `submit`, or it could be `Lähetä kysely`, or something exotic. You can, and normally should, use the `value` attribute to set this value, since it determines the text displayed in the button. It’s usually not desirable to have a submit button on your English-language appear with e.g. some text in Japanese just because a Japanese-language browser is being used.

So as others have written, the solution (if this is a problem) is to remove the `name` attribute. But since the `value` attribute should normally be used, you can make two changes simultaneously by just replacing the attribute name `name` by the name `value`, though you might also capitalize the word shown:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove name attribute from submit input

Answer (score 1):

remove the name attribute of the button.....